# $f: R \to R$ is s.t $\exists x_0$ s.t $f_{R\setminus\{x_o\}}$ is continuous then $f$ is Borel-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f: R \to R$ is s.t $\exists x_0$ s.t $f_{R \setminus \{x_o\}}$ is continuous, show that $f$ is Borel-measurable.

My attempt:

Let $V \subset R$ be open. I need to show $f^{-1}(V) \in \sigma(\Omega)$ the $\sigma$ algebra created by the open subsets of $R$.

If $x_0 \notin V$ then $f^{-1}_{R\setminus\{x_o\}}(V)$ is open, since the funtion is continuous.
Thus $f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}_{R\setminus\{x_o\}}(V) \in \sigma(\Omega)$

Otherwise $x_0 \in V$. Do you see a way to continue from here? I didn't find a way to finish my attempt by looking at $V$ without $x_0$ and working with 2 open subsets instead.

Comment: What is $f_{R/\{x_o\}}$ supposed to denote? Perhaps restriction of $f$ on $\Bbb R\setminus\{x_0\}$, but then the notation should look a bit different

Comment: yup, fixed. thanks